# Only one input/output device in pipewire

Tags: linux, audio, fedora, pipewire

I am running my headset using the AUX port. I am using the newest fedora version.
My problem is that every input and output is merged together into one: `Built-in Audio Analog Stereo`. This causes the problem that people can hear my system sounds (youtube, spotify, game sounds) while on a discord call.

This is the output I get running `pactl list`:
https://pastebin.com/QPsjAqDF

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware problem (pinout mismatch between the headset jack and the AUX port).

Comment: That isn't the issue, since the headset works perfectly fine on windows